# Incompatible pointer types 'struct tGlobal::instrStack *' and 'instrStack *'

Tags: c, pointers, struct, compilation

I have a small warning problem.
I have a global struct including all neccesary thing (flags, list of allocated memory etc.).
Its a global structure. So Im using it in all program.

Now I wanted to add there a pointer on instruction stack so I can just get to the datas like `global.iStack`

The structure of global is

```
struct tGlobal{
    .. some other thing in structure

    struct instrStack *iStack;
    struct mainTree *mTree;
};

extern struct tGlobal global;
```

And I have to initialize the stack. So I have a function with this prototype

```
instrStack* instrStackInit (instrStack* stc );
```

So in main I'm doing this

```
    struct instrStack dummyInstrStack;
    global.iStack = instrStackInit(&dummyInstrStack);
```

**But the Clion is displaying warning like Incompatible pointer types 'struct tGlobal::instrStack *' and 'instrStack *'**

But I'm adding pointer on that stack so there should be problem. Or I'm I wrong?

This thing happening mor etimes. Again in global struct when i want for sxample init the Binary tree and pointer on it insert into structure so I can easily acces the data wherever I want.

Can anyone help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

E: Declaration of instrStack

```
typedef struct {
    Instr **dataInstr;
    int count;
    int alloc;
}instrStack;
```

Comment: Where and how is declared  instrStack?

Comment: Added. Its declared in separate file included to both files (main and the file where tGlobal scturct is declared)

Comment: `tGlobal::instrStack` uses a C++ scope operator `::`. Are you compiling this as C or as C++?

Comment: Its pure C (I cant use any OOP)